# Persistent SSL problems in Chrome (and now possibly iOS simulator)

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome, ssl

Starting Saturday, I noticed that Chrome was blocking me from accessing some (but not all...) https sites (e.g. Github, Facebook). Googling lead to some links suggesting that a Digicert SSl certificate had expired, and suggested deleting the expired certificate. I did that and then reinstalled some root certificates from [the Digicert website](https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm) and the problem seemed to go away.

Now it has come back. The issue seems to be centered around one certificate "Digicert SHA2 Secure Server CA" which Chrome (and OSX keychain claim are "signed by an untrusted authority". And as a result sites that are signed by that certificate are still not working for me. Here's an example of what I'm seeing:

[SSL trust error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHyo8.png)

I know very little about SSL so I don't even know where to start with this problem. I've exhausted everything I can find on Google.

I'm also having a (possibly related) issue while developing an iPhone app in Xcode. I'm running an example app in the new Spotify iOS SDK and am getting errors saying "cannot open page. the address in invalid" during the Oauth dialog. I'm new to iOS and to the Spotify SDK so this may be totally unrelated but when I tried to load the initial authorization URL in Chrome I got an SSL error so I suspect they're linked.

I'm really stumped here and would appreciate any solution or even debugging suggestions.

Thanks!!

Comment: Sounds like you need to find a different certificate authority.

Comment: Make sure your system has the correct time.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich As far as I can tell I have the correct time (autosynced from Apple).

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan is it an option for me (the web client) to switch certificate authorities? If so could you point me to a guide how? (Google showed nothing I could understand as  useful)

Comment: Chrome uses the Operating System's certificate store. See Chromium's [Root Certificate Policy](http://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy). I managed to get the same irrelevant errors in Apple's Code Signing infrastructure by enforcing Basic Constraints and Key Usage in Keychain on a few of the CA's used in Apple's Developer Program (like the WWDR root). I would check and ensure *Digicert SHA2 Secure Server CA* is set to *Use System Defaults* in Keychain (which itemizes as *No Value Specified* for each purpose). Unless you don't trust them...

Comment: Unless you are implementing certificate pinning (i.e. you have client software that explicitly checks that your certificate is signed by a particular authority), it's safe to switch root certificates. In choosing which kind of SSL certificate to get, you should consider the trust list on most browsers and operating systems, the strength of the signing method (you should get a 2048-bit RSA certificate since 1024 and lower is too computationally weak), how much you trust the CA, whether you need an "extended validation" certificate or not (you probably don't), SNI, and cost.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan do you know any resources that explain how to go about switching root certificates? Google's not helping me much.